# Install golang library within subdirectory of Github repo

Tags: git, go, github

Normally Golang projects on Github are consumed by `go install` when there is a `src` folder at the root of the project. Right now I have a Git repo structured like so:

```
project/
  lang/
    typescript/
    java/
    golang/
        src/
        pkg/
```

is there a way to use `go install` against this git repo? Something like this:

```
go install 'github.com/org/project' --dir 'lang/golang'
```

anybody know if this is possible and how? Perhaps I can use `go get` first to get the right directory, and then `go install` after that?

**Update** - perhaps one solution is to use `go bundle` to package the library, and then install the go library with a url to the file?

Comment: why don't you just try the 'go get', 'go install' method you suggested? worst case scenario nothing happens.

Comment: @Pizzalord one reason we ask SO questions is so that they eventually help others with the same problem, also I really hate guessing around, but I suppose I could spend an hour with the docs

Comment: "I assume normally Golang projects in Github are consumed by go install when there is a src folder in top level of the project." Your assumptions are wrong. Questions based on wrong assumptions are hard to answer.

Comment: @Volker I took out the assume part, do you really not understand the question?

Comment: "Normally Golang projects on Github are consumed by go install when there is a src folder at the root of the project." is plain wrong.

Comment: often  the answer to questions like yours is someone just trying what you suggested might work. but i googled it for you just now :)

Comment: @Pizzalord excellent, you get points by upvote, and someone else will have a quick answer, everyone wins

Comment: I assume one solution is to pacakge your go library into a zip or tar file, similar to this NPM solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53628830/storing-multiple-npm-libraries-in-single-git-repo/53629105#53629105, there is `go bundle` but I tried it and failed to figure out how to use it.

Comment: @MrCholo "I assume one solution is to pacakge your go library into a zip or tar file, similar to this NPM solution [...] there is go bundle" No, this is totally wrong. You are deliberately trying to deviate from the official, working, proven, stable and used almost exclusively solution. Why? This just will lead to failure and frustration.

Answer (score 0):

Set `GOPATH` environment variable to the `project/lang/golang` directory and of your project (probably with a fully qualified path, i.e. one starting with `/` on unix-like systems). `go get` will install to the correct location. Other commands like `go build`/`go install` will also work properly.

Information about GOPATH:
https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH

How to set GOPATH:
https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH

You can also run the [`go help gopath`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable) command for more documentation.

Comment: I don't think you understood the OP. My project X is local, I am trying to install `project/lang/golang` as a dependency of X.

Comment: Then you would just install the dependency like any other go package. Do `go get github.com/org/project/lang/golang/src/thepackage`. You'd basically run `go get` with an argument that matches how you'd list the package in an `import` statement.

Answer (score -1):

from the go documentation [go command](https://golang.org/doc/articles/go_command.html)

after using

> $ go get github.com/google/codesearch/index
>
> $ go get github.com/petar/GoLLRB/llrb
>
> Both of these projects are now downloaded and installed into $HOME/go, which contains the two directories src/github.com/google/codesearch/index/ and src/github.com/petar/GoLLRB/llrb/, along with the compiled packages (in pkg/) for those libraries and their dependencies.

Comment: This assumes the `pkg` folder is in the root of the project/repo tho, doesn't it?

Comment: no the pkg folder is a folder you get when you install go it resides next to go/src, on my machine it is C:/Go/pkg and C:/Go/src, while my projects are in C:/user/username/projects

Comment: Ok I upvoted, somebody else downvoted, I am not sure why. I assume one solution is to package your go library into a zip or tar file, similar to this NPM solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53628830/storing-multiple-npm-libraries-in-single-git-repo/53629105#53629105

Comment: that should not be need for go, using go get should get the package and all of its dependencies