# Storing multiple NPM libraries in single Git repo

Tags: git, github, npm, npm-install

We can reference NPM deps on Github like so:

```
"dependencies":{
   "foo":"github.com/org/root#commit"
}
```

But I have a Git repo with multiple NPM libraries in it, like so:

```
root/
  nodejs/
    foo/
      package.json
    bar/
      package.json
```

is there a way to install foo from this Github repo directly? Something like this?

```
"dependencies":{
   "foo":"github.com/org/root/nodejs/foo#commit"
}
```

I tried installing using that url, and it didn't work, I got this error:

> ```
> npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
> npm ERR! package.json Non-registry package missing package.json: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/org/root/master/nodejs/foo/package.json.
> npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /home/oleg/.npm/_logs/2018-12-05T09_15_28_666Z-debug.log
> ```

I also tried using raw.githubusercontent.com like so:

```
"dependencies":{
   "foo":"raw.githubusercontent.com/org/root/nodejs/foo#commit"
}
```

And I got the same error. Surely this must be possible somehow?

Comment: Similar question on NPM community: https://npm.community/t/storing-multiple-npm-libraries-packages-in-one-git-repo/3844

Answer (score 0):

Ok so one solution is to use tarballs. So you can use this command:

```
 npm i -S 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/org/root/master/nodejs/foo/foo-0.0.1001.tgz'
```

it worked..and I get this in package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "foo": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/org/root/master/nodejs/foo/foo-0.0.1001.tgz"
  }
```

basically all you need to do is npm install with a url that points to a tarball.

Comment: obviously won't work very well with semver, since we are stuck one exact version, but hey